# Are backticks possible in AHK hotstring?

Tags: autohotkey

I need to have a hotstring with backticks in it (`) surrounding it. Simplifying what I've tried:

```
::`hw`::Hello, World!
```

Running it gives an error: "Invalid hotkey".

I'm not sure why this restriction exists but more to the point: is there any workaround?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A backtick (`` ` ``) is the [default escape character](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/_EscapeChar.htm) in AHK.
In order to specifiy a literal backtick, you can either escape it (with itself):

```
::``hw``::Hello, World!
```

Or change the escape character:

```
#EscapeChar \
::`hw`::Hello, World!
```

I wouldn't recommend the latter, since many libraries expect the escape char to be a backtick.